# Is the gameobject is on the same level with it's surface on which it is located?(Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, bounds, vertices

I am pretty new to Unity and maybe my question would be not clear for you but I will try to explain. I have a coffeemachine virtual prototype in unity and there are 3 buttons on coffee machine. What I want to do is to find out if the buttons are on the same level with the surface(plane) on which these buttons are located or they raised above it. It will be great if someone will give me some direction on how can I do it.

Comment: What is the purpose? Does the plane actually matter? I ask because if you just want to monitor the state of the button (pressed/not pressed) just use a variable and draw the button accordingly.

Comment: The purpose is just to check out whether the button on the coffee machine is raised above the surface or no.  I do not want to check the state of the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the `Transform` game component on the inspector. For example if you're trying to know if they're vertically aligned you can always just check they `Y Position` field on there and make sure if they're the same or not. You can also drag (Move / `W` shortcut) the object while holding `Ctrl + Shift` which will put an object on top of another. You can also press `V` while in Move to drag an object using its vertex and pin it to another vertex you drag it too. Hope this helps, Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Actually what exactly I have to do is to determine if the button is on the same level with the surface , from the script  by using the mesh vertices. The local position does not say anything about the surfaces of the objects and also I think the local positions cannot be compared with each other as they are relative to the corresponding parent objects. This means, two identical local positions can be completely different when considering the world space. If you can help with this it will be perfect. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Alright so I don't exactly understand your problem but if you're trying to check if the two objects are touching you can use mesh colliders and OnCollisionEnter if you're trying to put an object exactly on the surface on another one you can use colliders and rigidbodies or you can drag the object holding Ctrl + Shift but if your problem isn't one of there please clarify it more